# Kylo security implementation, OpenLDAP implementation in Kylo with Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, openldap, kylo

We Are trying to integrate Kylo with OpenLDAP and Kerberos, but it seems like there are no configuration changes suggested in Kylo doc.

https://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/KyloKerberosSPNEGO.html

only auth-ad changes are suggested in the document, but nothing for OpenLDAP.

Can anyone please suggest some solutions? Thanks in advance :)